# How to search for all files containing 2 specific strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, visual-studio, find

In my Visual Studio I'd like to find all the files that contain 2 specific words (say, `UpdatePanel` and `DropDownCheckList` in a solution or project). In other words, I like to find all the files using my home-made webserver control `DropDownCheckList` with the ASP.NET control `UpdatePanel`.

[image: how to find all files containing 2 specific words]

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on your Visual Studio Version. [Since VS 2013 they use .net regexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) in their search dialogue, so the solution would look something like:

```
^(?s)(?=.*Foobar)(?=.*Test)
```

`(?=...)` is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

`(?s)` is an [inline modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to make the `.` matches also newline characters

with an older version, there is a special kind of regex flavour used, so you can not use lookaheads:

```
(Foobar(.|\n)+Test)|(Test(.|\n)+Foobar)
```

here I used an alternation to match first word A, then word B OR first word B then word A.

`(.|\n)+` is a workaround to match either any character or a newline character.

Comment: Nice answer. Alternation would be more than acceptable for only two terms but the length of the expression grows exponentially with the amount of terms to search, as you have to cater for all order of occurrences.

Comment: Also I believe that `^(?s)(?=.*Foobar)(?=.*Test)` won't work even in the newer versions of visual studio since it matches for all files! Almost as if the expression is being applied to all the files joined together.

Comment: @JonM, I don't have a VS 2013 available here to test, but I am quite sure it will work that way. I am not sure were your problem is with "matches for all files". I don't think that they join all the files together, that would make no sense.

Comment: I am on VS2010, tried ^(?s)(?=.*Foobar)(?=.*Test) and it had not worked (searched all filed in solution with no result, though I am on one such file opened)

Comment: @Fulproof, then use the second part of my answer. I also tested it on VS2010.

Comment: @Fulproof, the lookaheads are not working in VS till 2010, they use a [strange regex flavour](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html) there till then.

Comment: OK, the second one: `(UpdatePanel(.|\n)+DropDownCheckList)|(DropDownCheckList(.|\n)+UpdatePanel)` worked, very slow and completely freezing all parts of VS

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this in visual studio. Make sure you set the find dialogue to use regular expressions. Also got this working in the notepad++ 'Find In Files' function configured to look at the relevant project directory. They both use the same expression:

```
(?is)\A^.(?=(?:(?!\Z).)*?DropDownCheckList)(?=(?:(?!\Z).)*?UpdatePanel)
```

It will find the required terms in all files that include them, no matter the order.

Comment: Something is wrong. I entered this expression according the screenshot in my question into "Find what:" field with "Use:" "Regular Expressions" checked and got error: "Find all "(?is)\A^.(?=(?:(?!\Z).)*?DropDownCheckList)(?=(?:(?!\Z).)*?UpdatePanel)", Regular expressions, Subfolders, Find Results 1, "Entire Solution", "*.as?x"
Argument is missing in the pattern."

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Why do you add all those `\A` and `\Z` anchors?