# Search Multiple string using Visual Studio IDE Find and Replace

Tags: visual-studio

I want to find multiple string from a line in files. For example,

> **This is sample text**

I can able to find the string **`is sample text`** in the line.

But just I want to find the string contains the strings **`is`** and **`text`**. Is it possible to find  using **`Visual Studio IDE "Find and Replace"`**?

> Is there any other way to find multiple strings using **Visual Studio IDE**?

Comment: @dwana Not using any Languages... Using `Visual Studio IDE` **FIND AND REPLACE**... I am not going to replace anything... Just I want to find the strings...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I myself found the solution for this.

Using **`Use Regular Expression`** option in `Find and Replace` dialog. I entered following in `Search term` text box and find.

> **is(.*)text**

I got the result as expected.

Comment: It's worth pointing out, this requires your words are in the order you specify (Which may or may not work depending on your situation) This seems like a better solution to searching for two seperate words in unknown locations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060503/how-to-search-for-all-files-containing-2-specific-strings

Answer (score 8):

Check the regular expression box and type:

- 'is' or 'text':    `is|text`
- 'is' and 'text':   `is.*text`

Comment: OP asked for "contains the strings is *and* text", this is "contains the strings is *or* text"

Comment: You can use 
is.*text

Answer (score 0):

You can try either wild card or regular expression.
Choose "Use" checkbox, select "WildCard" from the drop-down and type "is*text".

This should be able to find "is sample text" for you..

Hope that helps.

-Milind

Comment: I already answered for this... But I tried with your string `is*text`, it is not working... Did you try?

Comment: @Jesuraja Yes it does, I answered after trying. Make sure you choose "wildcards" in the drop-down and not "regular expression". If regular expression is chosen, your way is right.